# bower build failing to execute git ls

Tags: bower, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a `bower install` build step which throws an error for this file:

```
bower file-saver.js#~1.20150507.2
```

Error:

> ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
> [https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git"](https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git%22), exit code of #128
> fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
> fatal: Cannot prompt because user interactivity has been disabled.
> remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13,
> 2021. Please use a personal access token instead. remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/
> for more information. fatal: Authentication failed for
> 'https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git/'

Given all I need to do is fix a build step and I do have (or wish to use) a git PAT, how can I resolve this error? I am not directly referencing the specified version of the bower package, either, so this is a dependency I can't control (AFAIK).

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with this approach: As @ceeno-qi-msft mentioned, Bower is not supported any more...

But the trivial reason why it's not working at this time is, that the [Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git](https://github.com/Teleborder/FileSaver.js.git) repo was deleted :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/what-happened-to-bower/), the Bower has been gradually faded away out from Oct. 2017.

And we have a workaround for you

1.You could remove your file saving line in bower json file

2.Installing this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-file-saver), with "npm install --save file-saver@1.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

As Lat Tegonal has mentioned, it is because Teleborder/FileSaver.js git repo was deleted.  I tried to solve it with npm, but I could not figure out how to get rid of the errors.  As such, I solved it by creating a script tag with CDN address in the index.html that gets served from the server. Use the first bundle.min.js from below:

```
https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-file-saver
```

And insert this tag: `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-file-saver/1.1.3/angular-file-saver.bundle.min.js'></script>`

into your index.html.  For me, it was in server/views folder, may or may not be the same for you.

I hope this helps someone - a rather niche issue and took a while to solve.